# How to loop within the .each() function inside the UL tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make this dynamic. So I have 9 images and I want to change the width(px) increasing by 10px and when reached fifth image it should be decreasing to the original size by 10px. So far I got to increase all the way.

```
$( ".org-collections li img" ).each(function( index ) {
  var index = index+"9";
  var calc = 150+parseInt(index);

  if(calc == 199){

  } 
  $(this).css("max-width",calc+"px");
});
```

Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ob1uwy97/).

Example:
[image]

Comment: can't you do something like `index+ $( ".org-collections li img" ).length`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it needs to be looping up and down. The .length gives me the number of `li` . Not sure what you are suggesting precisely..

Comment: Is it the width you want to change, or the height? Your code is affecting the width, but your image suggests it's the height you want to increase and decrease (or possibly both).

Comment: @RobinZigmond, the max-width. The height is controlled by CSS automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically the calculation you want to do. I've been playing in JSFiddle to get the "best-looking" values of the constants involved, feel free to alter them to suit:

(Note that the maximum value, which I've got as 150 here, doesn't work too well if you make it much higher - I assume it's to do with the intrinsic dimensions of the image, it doesn't seem to want to get taller than a particular value.)

```
$( ".org-collections li img" ).each(function( index ) {
  var calc = 150 - 9*Math.abs(4 - index);
  $(this).css("max-width",calc+"px");
});
```

Also, the value of 4 works because it's the middle value, assuming you've got exactly 9 images (as you do here). If you might have a variable number `n`, then as long as it's odd then you can replace 4 by `(n - 1) / 2`

Comment: This looks good but I should have mentioned the 5th title needs to have around `221px`

Comment: Well change the 150 to 221 then. I thought I tried higher values earlier and it didn't work well for the middle images, but I just tried 221 and it seemed to be OK. As I said, you can adjust the values (specifically the 150 and the 9) to suit.